# Getting back in touch with hiring manager!

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer

I interviewed for a position in a different state about 6 months ago. My husband's job was asking him to come there, so I started looking for a job. The hiring manager really liked me and gave me a call a few days after with a job offer. During that time, I found out that I was pregnant and decided to stay where I was around my family until we had the baby. I spoke with the hiring manager at the time and told him about my pregnancy. He completely understood and told me that I need to do what's best for the family. 2 months later, I had a miscarriage and lost the baby. And now, my husband is thinking of moving out there for his job. Would it be ok for me to contact the hiring manager now? What's the best way to go about this? I would really like to take the job since I know that I'll be moving there now.

Comment: Go for it! It should like you last contacted him on good terms and it seems that he is understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely you should contact him.  Use the same means of communicating with him as you used previously, and simply state that your circumstances have changed and you would very much like to discuss further the position they offered.

You don't need to offer details as to why your circumstances have changed.  If he has any sort of empathy he will figure it out and not mention it to you.

Answer (score 1):

That job is probably not still available.  But it wouldn't hurt to let him know that you are again considering moving out there, and will let him know when you actually arrive.  You don't need to give details, just let him know that circumstances have changed, and you're expecting to be in the area in n months.

He probably doesn't want to consider you until you are actually there, because things may change again.  But if you let him know you are coming, he may keep you in mind for a future job coming open.

And if the previous job is still open, letting him know that you are coming will open up that discussion again.  If he does offer again, you probably need to either take it or let that company go completely.  He's not likely to offer a third time.